# Cannot select same item twice from android listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to be able to select the same item from a ListView consecutive times in order to trigger an event which is to play audio. On my phone running android 7.1.1 I have to select a different item before being able to select the same item again. On my old phone running android 4.4 I could select the same item multiple times.

```
private ListView listPhrases;

listPhrases.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          Phrase selectedPhrase = phraseArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
          SoundHelper.getInstance(getActivity()).PlayPhrase(selectedPhrase);

        }
    });
```

The event only fires the first time you tap the item.

```
public void PlayPhrase(Phrase phrase) {
    if (soundIDs.containsKey(phrase.pid)) {
        int soundId = soundIDs.get(phrase.pid);
        soundPool.play(soundId, actVolume, actVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, phrase.secondLanguage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: I dont see anything wrong, pls show code for SoundHelper